# Autofix picture feature in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, photo

I want to use the autofix feature for a picture which is used inside my application is there any way I could include the autofix feature in my application for fixing the images automatically or else is there any code available which could do the same feature.Please give me some inputs.

Thanks,
Mugu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use autofix from 3rd party applications. If you want a similar feature, look at Rene's [WriteableBitmapEx library](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/).